# Getting an error while importing Appium Libary in eclipse

Tags: python-appium

When i importing the Appium Library in eclipse getting an error.
I have created Robot framework using Python. when i importing appium library getting an error not able to resolve the issue. can you pls help on the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmTZp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly defined the Appium library in your robot file. You can do one thing , Create a new sample robot file and try to import the appium library in it. Check whether it is working or not.This is the only way you can check it because there is no other way to resolve it.